# Как сделать массив из GameObject в C#?

Tags: c#, массивы, unity3d, visual-studio

Как сделать массив из GameObject в C# и обращаться к ним для их невидимости? Вот GameObject которые надо пихнуть в массив:

```
public GameObject pot_1; 
public GameObject pot_2; 
public GameObject pot_3; 
public GameObject pot_4; 
public GameObject pot_5; 
public GameObject pot_6; 
public GameObject pot_7; 
public GameObject pot_8; 
public GameObject pot_9; 
public GameObject pot_10;
```

И ещё, где надо создавать массив, в методе Start или же просто в Class?

Comment: *"Как сделать массив из GameObject"* --- точно так же, как и массив любого другого типа. А как это конкретно делается - написано в любой литературе по языку C# для новичков

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-c)

Comment: *"где надо создавать массив, в методе Start или же просто в Class?"* --- зависит от задач и необходимостей

Comment: `public GameObject[] pots` только непонятно, надо сформировать массив из 10 объектов, сохранённых в этих полях или заменить эту стопку на массив? Задача не ясна

Answer (score -1, accepted):

вот так в Start пихай `GameObject[] pots = new GameObject[10] {pot_1,pot_2,pot_3,pot_4,pot_5,pot_6,pot_7,pot_8,pot_9,pot_10}`